# Cant Set Apollo Local State with nested values

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks, apollo-boost

I'm testing out Apollo Graphql with React and I'm trying to update the local state with Apollo Graphql with a nested object. I'm running into an issue. The data returns a `null` value and does not even return the value I set as a default. The only warning I see is `Missing field __typename`. I'm not sure what I'm missing or if this is not how you properly set nested values with Graphql or Apollo issue. I have a code sandbox with the example I'm trying to do https://codesandbox.io/embed/throbbing-river-xwe2y

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import App from "./App";

import "./styles.css";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      name: {
        firstName: "Michael",
        lastName: "Jordan"
      }
    },
    resolvers: {},
    typeDefs: `
      type Query {
        name: FullName
      }

      type FullName {
        firsName: String
        lastName: String
      }
    `
  }
});

client.writeData({
  data: {
    name: {
      firstName: "Kobe",
      lastName: "Bryant"
    }
  }
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Name from "./Name";
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

function App() {
  const client = useApolloClient();

  client.writeData({
    data: {
      name: {
        firstName: "Lebron",
        lastName: "James"
      }
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Name />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Name.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NAME } from "./Queries";
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const Name = async props => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const { loading, data } = await client.query({ query: NAME });
  console.log(data);

  return <div>Hello {data.name.firstName}</div>;
};

export default Name;
```

QUERIES.js

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_NAME = gql`
  {
    name @client {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apollo Client's documentation is not good in this manner and simply starts using `__typename` without properly explaining the reasoning behind it directly. I've seen other engineers struggling to understand its purpose before. As the warning is suggesting, you must pass a `__typename` property to objects you write directly to the cache, as Apollo Client will use this value by default in its data normalization process internally, to save/identify the data.

On all your calls to `client.writeData`, you should include a `__typename` property, like:

```js
client.writeData({
  data: {
    name: {
      __typename: 'FullName', // this is the name of the type this data represents, as you defined in your typeDefs
      firstName: 'Lebron',
      lastName: 'James',
    },
  },
});
```

Also, you can't use `async/await` on the `render` method of your component -- in the case of function components, the main body itself, as Promises are not valid React elements. So you have two options:

- switch from `client.query` to the `useQuery` hook; or
- since you're only requesting client-side fields, you can use the `client.readQuery` method which is synchronous and will return the data to you without a Promise. Note that with this method you're only able to make client-side requests, i.e if you want to request client and server fields at the same time, it won't work.